# Post data to database through cakephp from javascript

Tags: php, ajax, rest, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakePHP and trying to figure out how to send data to php through javascript

I have a local storage object:

```
0: {title: "test1", price: "1", imageSrc: "1.jpg"}
1: {title: "test2", price: "2", imageSrc: "2.jpg"}
2: {title: "test3", price: "3", imageSrc: "3.jpg"}
```

Then there is a button I want to use to submit data from local storage:

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Checkout', ["class" => "cart__button js-submit"]) ?>
```

After clicking on this button:

```
...
if($el.classList.contains('js-submit')) {
  var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url : "<?php echo $this->Url->build( [ 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'buy' ] ); ?>",
    data: {cart:cart},
    success: function( response ){     
      console.log(response)
    }
  });
}
```

I tried to use ajax but it gives me an error

What should I do next? How to pass data to Controller and save data in database?

Comment: Have you tried catching the form submission and submitting via [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)?

Comment: What to do next? You should fix the Ajax error. Since you haven't given us any information about the error you get, it's hard for us to help you with that.